# Has anyone created an ics iCalendar generator function that works with Google Calendar?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm trying to generate an .ics file that imports successfully into Google calendar. Google Calendar is proving especially difficult (I've got Outlook and Apple iCal working perfectly).

Does anyone have a php function or class which creates the right headers and inserts events that's been proven to work with Google calendar?

Answer (score 2):

I also see this is an older post, but with no accepted answer.

Recently, I needed to implement ical generation into my web app... but mine also required recurring events with a given formula. For this, I used a combination of the following packages:

1. For ical generation: https://github.com/markuspoerschke/iCal
2. For recurring events: https://github.com/simshaun/recurr

I use recurr to generate a list of dates based on a recurrence formula:

```
public function generate_dates_array(\DateTime $end_date = null) : array
{
    if(! $end_date) {
        $end_date = new \DateTime('midnight');
    }

    $rule = new \Recurr\Rule($this->recurrence_rule, $this->created_at->setTime(0,0));

    $rule->setUntil($end_date);

    $transformer = new ArrayTransformer();

    $dates = $transformer->transform($rule);

    $dateArray = [];

    foreach($dates as $date) {
        $dateArray[] = $date->getStart();
    }

    return $dateArray;
}
```

Then setup my calendar:

```
$vCalendar = new \Eluceo\iCal\Component\Calendar('YourUrlHere');
$vCalendar->setName('YOUR NAME HERE');
$vCalendar->setDescription('YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE');
```

Then loop over those dates adding events to my calendar object... making sure to adjust my times to UTC from the user's chosen timezone.

```
$today = new Carbon();
$end_date = $today->addMonth();

foreach($events as $event) {
  $dates = $event->generate_dates_array($end_date); // function shown in above code snippet
  $duration = $event->duration ? $event->duration : 30;

  // Each Occurrence for event
  foreach($dates as $date) {
    $vEvent = new \Eluceo\iCal\Component\Event();

    $date_string = "{$date->format('Y-m-d')} {$event->time}";

    $start_time = new Carbon($date_string, $user->time_zone);
    $start_time->setTimezone('UTC');
    $vEvent->setDtStart($start_time);

    $end_time = new Carbon($date_string, $user->time_zone);
    $end_time = $end_time->addMinutes($duration);
    $end_time->setTimezone('UTC');
    $vEvent->setDtEnd($end_time);

    $vEvent->setNoTime(false);
    $vEvent->setSummary($event->name);
    $vEvent->setDescription("$event->description");
    $vCalendar->addComponent($vEvent);
  }
}
```

After everything is setup properly, I output the calendar. This means I can use the URL that generates this file to import the calendar into Google Calendar (or any other calendar program) and it'll ping it daily for updates. (URL must be publicly accessibly, which required I used a guid as the identifier instead of user_id, by the way)

```
header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
echo $vCalendar->render();
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else landing here!

Answer (score 1):

This is an old one, and the only answer wasn't accepted, so not sure if the below code fixed your issue.  However, I came across this in my own searches to try to fix a bug I had, and now that I have a solution, I figured I would share it.  The below code has been tested with the latest Outlook and with Gmail.

With outlook what was causing my bug was that I was using `\n` instead of `\r\n` for the event details. So, as you'll see below, I use `\r\n` for the event and \n for everythign else so that PHP processes it correctly. Perhaps a similar problem was causing the issues with gmail?

> Warning, this code does nothing to prevent header injection, please
>   use responsibly ;-)

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    //CONFIGURE HERE
    $fromName           = "John Doe";
    $fromEmail          = "john.doe@example.com";
    $toName             = "Your Name";
    $toEmail            = 'yourname@example.com';
    $start              = new DateTime('2017-08-15 15:00');
    $end                = new DateTime('2017-08-15 16:00');
    $summary            = "Hello World Event";
    //END CONFIGURATION

    $uid                = "0123456789";
    $headers            = array();
    $boundary           = "_CAL_" . uniqid("B",true) . "_B_";
    $headers[]          = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[]          = "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"";
    $headers[]          = "To: \"{$toName}\" <{$toEmail}>";
    $headers[]          = "From: \"{$fromName}\" <{$fromEmail}>";

    $calendarLines      = array(
        "BEGIN:VCALENDAR",
        "METHOD:REQUEST",
        "PRODID:-//PHP//MeetingRequest//EN",
        "VERSION:2.0",
        "BEGIN:VEVENT",
        "ORGANIZER;CN={$fromName}:MAILTO:{$fromEmail}",
        "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN={$toName}:MAILTO:{$toEmail}",
        "DESCRIPTION:{$summary}",
        "SUMMARY:{$summary}",
        "DTSTART:".$start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "DTEND:".$end->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "UID:{$uid}",
        "CLASS:PUBLIC",
        "PRIORITY:5",
        "DTSTAMP:".gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        "TRANSP:OPAQUE",
        "STATUS:CONFIRMED",
        "SEQUENCE:0",
        "LOCATION:123 Any Street",
        "BEGIN:VALARM",
        "ACTION:DISPLAY",
        "DESCRIPTION:REMINDER",
        "TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT15M",
        "END:VALARM",
        "END:VEVENT",
        "END:VCALENDAR"
    );


    $calendarBase64     = base64_encode(implode("\r\n",$calendarLines));
    //ensure we don't have lines longer than 70 characters for older computers:
    $calendarResult     = wordwrap($calendarBase64,68,"\n",true);

    $emailLines = array(
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso - 8859 - 1\"",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable",
        "",
        "<html><body>",
        "<h1>Hello World</h1>",
        "<p>This is a calendar event test</p>",
        "</body></html>",
        "",
        "--{$boundary}",
        "Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=\"utf - 8\"; method=REQUEST",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
        "",
        $calendarResult,
        "",
        "--{$boundary}--"
    );
    $emailContent   = implode("\n",$emailLines);

    $headersResult      = implode("\n",$headers);
    mail($toEmail, $summary, $emailContent, $headersResult );
    echo("<pre>".htmlentities($headersResult)."\n\n".htmlentities($emailContent)."</pre>");
    echo("<br /><br />");
    echo("<pre>".base64_decode($calendarResult)."</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing but just created a URL instead of an iCal.

Check out https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/3033039

Fill out the form and generate HTML then in the php file I was using to create the ical i just created a separate thing to replace the details with variables.

EG:

```
if($calType === "iCal"){
    //set correct content-type-header
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=AddToCalendar.ics');
    header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');

    $desc = str_replace("\n", '\n', $desc);
    $desc = str_replace(array("\r","\n","\r"), '', $desc);

    $ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Smartershows.com//TheBatteryShow//EN
X-WR-CALNAME;CHARSET=utf-8:".$subj."
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY;CHARSET=utf-8:".$subj."
LOCATION;CHARSET=utf-8:".$loc."
URL:".$url."
UID:30fc985de98ed0dabfeb13722e3c82259fcd33e3 
DESCRIPTION:".$desc."
DTSTART:".$sDate."T".$sTime."
DTEND:".$eDate."T".$eTime."
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";

return $ical;
exit;
}else if($calType === "gCal"){

    $href = "http://www.google.com/calendar/event?";
    $href .= "action=TEMPLATE";
    $href .= "&text=".urlencode($subj);
    $href .= "&dates=".$sDate."T".$sTime."/".$eDate."T".$eTime;
    $href .= "&details=".urlencode($desc);
    $href .= "&location=".urlencode($loc);
    $href .= "&trp=false";
    $href .= "&sprop=".urlencode($subj);
    $href .= "&sprop=name:".urlencode($url);

    return '<a href="'.$href.'" target="_blank"><strong>Download for Gmail</strong></a>';

}
```

So the first block in the if is making the ical and the second is taking the same info to build a url that google will take and populate a calendar page.

The downside of this though is that you can only put basic things into the description...not a lot of fancy html or anything...unless you htmlencode everything i guess but even then im not sure what the character limit of a url is...

Hotmail and Yahoo mail can both populate calendars this way as well but unfortunately neither have a nice tool (that i can find) that generates a link beforehand that you can use.

Hope this helps!